# Не обновляется Text при изменении значения в MutableState<User>

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop

Подскажите почему не обновляется компонент Text при изменении значения в MutableState

```
fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        App()
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val user = remember{ mutableStateOf(User(name = "Yura", age = 50)) }
    
    MaterialTheme {
        Column {
            Text(text = "Имя- ${user.value.name} Возраст- ${user.value.age}")
            Button(onClick = {
                user.value.name = "Sasha"
                user.value.age = 31
            }) {
                Text("Go")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
data class User(
    var name: String,
    var age: Int
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что `MutableState` у вас отслеживает меняется ли сам инстанс `User`, а не его содержимое. Вот так должно работать.

```
Button(onClick = {
    user.value = User(name = "Sasha", age = 31)
}) {
    Text("Go")
}
```

А `data class User` можете сделать immutable.